# Adding a table on the bottom of existing content on a PDF page with Itext

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to produce a document from a PDF template with forms, where the second page should be repeated N types with different form values. For such a purpose, I need to copy the second page, change the fields names,set their values and start again.

I have managed to do it correctly by using PdfSmartCopy, however on a page I would need to add a table just below a form.

How can I correctly add a table below a form, given that I have a PdfStamper in scope?

Comment: *What have you tried?* The form fields have coordinates. Use those coordinates to determine the position of the table. Add the table using the `writeSelectedRows()` method.

Comment: It's the right answer, however I will switch to a proper templating solution (Freemarker) and convert it to pdf. If you give the answer I will accept it and close it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form fields have coordinates. You can get these coordinates using the [getFieldPositions()](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/AcroFields.html#getFieldPositions%28java.lang.String%29) method. This returns a series of [FieldPosition](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/AcroFields.FieldPosition.html) objects (one for each widget that corresponds with a specific field) that will give you a page number and a rectangle value. Use those coordinates to determine the position of the table.

Add the table at those coordinates using the [writeSelectedRows()](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html#writeSelectedRows%28int,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte%29) method.